# How Java calls a JNI function which is named with JNI naming rule?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

It's easy to know how Java calls the JNI functions which are registered in JNI_OnLoad(). Their function pointers are stored in JniEnv.

But if a function is named with the JNI naming rule, such as Java_com_example_XXX_helloJni, it's not registerred in JNI_OnLoad(). So how is it called?

Actually what I want to do is loading a typical library in native code and then calling its functions from Java code. This library has some functions with ruled names. And I hope to call these functions in Java code WITHOUT loading the library in Java code.

To make it more understandable, the process is like:

1) Java Code -> load library A

2) library A -> load library B

3) Java Code -> call library B's functions

So from my understanding, B's functions should be called successfully, because:

1) B's functions are named with JNI naming rule and exported

2) System.LoadLibrary() just did two main things: dlopen() + dlsym("JNI_OnLoad), which is just what I did while loading B

But I failed. B's functions could not be called. The error is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to register B's function in B's JNI_OnLoad() and succeeded to call these functions from Java code.

Comment: "The error is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" and the text of that exception is? and the Java native method declaration? and the C declaration? and definition?

Comment: The declarations are all correct. I think the problem is JNI could not found the functions. So if I registered the functions in JNI_OnLoad, it works.

Comment: You don't have to do that if the declarations are correct. *Ergo* they aren't.

Comment: The fact is I have to. Library B is loaded by Library A, not by Java code. So I failed to call B's functions from Java code, although I name the functions correctly. I have to register these functions in B's JNI_OnLoad, which is called manually by A.

Comment: To chain `JNI_OnLoad()` from **libA** to **libB** is a clever trick, and this should work. Another option is to call `System.LoadLibrary("B")` from libA (`env->FindClass("java/lang/System")`, an so on). I personally prefer the `JNI_OnLoad()` approach, because this way you can keep the list of exported symbols short.

Comment: Nice. JNI_Onload() approach is easier but if B has not implemented JNI_OnLoad(), it won't work out. The another option you raised is really brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNI functions named with JNINameString is called by dvmResolveNativeMethod in Native.cpp. The detailed process is:
dvmResolveNativeMethod -> dvmLookupInternalNativeMetho -> lookupSharedLibMethod -> findMethodInLib -> dlsym